# Gridview's UPDATE does not like the space in my parameter

Tags: asp.net, gridview, webforms

Unfortunately, the database I'm dealing with has a space in the column name. I have a DropDownList in a GridView and I'm trying to update the column with whatever the user selects in the DropDownList. Here's how I have the DropDownList:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Phase (edit)" SortExpression="EditedPhase">
    <EditItemTemplate>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="PhaseDropDownList" runat="server" DataSourceID="PhaseDropDown" DataTextField="Current Project Phase" DataValueField="Current Project Phase" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("Phase") %>'>
        </asp:DropDownList>
    </EditItemTemplate>
<asp:TemplateField>
```

Here's the data source:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="PhaseDropDown" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ODSConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="select distinct [Current Project Phase] from [Phase_Table]">
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Here's how I have my update command and the parameter:

```
UpdateCommand="UPDATE [Pipeline] SET EditedPhase = @[Current Project Phase]"

<UpdateParameters>
    <asp:Parameter Name="[Current Project Phase]" Type="String"/>
</UpdateParameters>
```

After doing a little bit of research, I discovered that you can not have spaces in the parameter, but most of the solutions used the code behind. I have no code behind because introducing code behind could potentially break it (needing to deal with page loads and such). How do I fix my current issue?

If there's a typo, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, do not use spaces in your parameter name; the value passed to the parameter can have spaces though, so I'm not sure if that is a point of confusion.  For instance, update your SQL query like:

```
UpdateCommand="UPDATE [Pipeline] SET EditedPhase = @CurrentProjectPhase">
<UpdateParameters>
    <asp:Parameter Name="CurrentProjectPhase" Type="String" DefaultValue="Current Project Phase"/>
</UpdateParameters>
```

Here the value (the DefaultValue is a default to supply to the update when no value is provided) can have spaces just fine.  But the name cannot.  You can set the DefaultValue of the parameter in code or use a more capable parameter (like session, control parameters) to grab values from something...

Comment: I took a different approach. I decided to use an alias, thanks anyways.